# How to generate password using slider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am creating a Password Manager Application and when user entering his details then I wont to show them a slider which generates a password in upper Password field. I have created a some code but i am not getting result as expected when user click on **GENERATE PASSWORD** the it show the following output.

[image]

Expected output:-

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class PasswordInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PasswordInputState createState() => _PasswordInputState();
}

class _PasswordInputState extends State<PasswordInput> {
  bool _obscureText = true;
  int generatePasswordHelper = 0;
  String _passwordStrength = "Hello";
  int _currentRangeValues = 6;

  void _toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }

  Widget WebsiteName() {
    return TextFormField(
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Name of website",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget WebsiteAddress() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Website address",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget UserName() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Username / Email",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget Password() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      obscureText: _obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Password",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            _obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
            color: Colors.grey.shade600,
          ),
          onPressed: _toggle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget Note() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      maxLines: null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Note",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget GeneratePassword() {
    this.generatePasswordHelper = 0;
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
            ),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                  text: "GENERATE PASSWORD",
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      setState(() {
                        generatePasswordHelper = 1;
                      });
                    })
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget PasswordGenerator() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      //height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Text(
                  _passwordStrength,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    generatePasswordHelper = 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Slider(
            value: _currentRangeValues.toDouble(),
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            divisions: 27,
            onChanged: (double newValue) {
              setState(() {
                _currentRangeValues = newValue.round();
              });
            },
            semanticFormatterCallback: (double newValue) {
              return '${newValue.round()} dollars';
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Add Password"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                WebsiteName(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                WebsiteAddress(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                UserName(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Password(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    if (generatePasswordHelper == 0)
                      GeneratePassword()
                    else
                      PasswordGenerator()
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Note(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    child: Ink(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          end: Alignment.centerRight,
                          colors: [
                            Color(0xffff5f6d),
                            Color(0xffff5f6d),
                            Color(0xffffc371),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            maxWidth: double.infinity, minHeight: 50),
                        child: Text(
                          "Submit",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an initalValue to your password field. Init a variable with a default blank value, then when you generate a password save it in that variable and use it as the password field value

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/initialValue.html

```
class _PasswordInputState extends State<PasswordInput> {
  bool _obscureText = true;
  int generatePasswordHelper = 0;
  String _passwordStrength = "Hello";
  int _currentRangeValues = 6;
  String currentPassword = ""
  ...

  Widget Password() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      obscureText: _obscureText,
      initialValue: currentPassword
      ...
```

When you generate a password save it in currentPassword using setState

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer and now I understand how to generate the password and show it in the Password field but as you see in expected output the Slider is of gradient color and when we slide it then where we stop sliding that color also reflect on upper Text. i.e. Strong Password, Week Password etc., so how it can be done and how to disable that creepy white color of slider division??

Comment: Wrap your Slider with a SliderTheme https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderTheme-class.html and provide your theme to the "track"(I haven't tried this part). Use your variable _currentRangeValues  to generate a color that reflect the slider position on the track and then pass that color to your Text(_passwordStrength,).